# Swift: DispatchQueue.main.async stops updating the UI after a while

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, user-interface, program-entry-point

I have a custom made image picker containing a UICollectionView. When each cell is selected, I want my indicator to be displayed in the cell while the image is getting fetched from its asset and lastly update the cell UI once the image has been fetched.

I managed to get everything working by including the background operations (fetching, storing the image) in a background thread while updating the UI in the main thread. However, after having selected 8-12 images, it stops displaying the indicator view, which is supposed to be done in the first **DispatchQueue.main.async** call. Here is my code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    ...

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.showIndicator()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let image = HelperFunctions().getAssetImage(asset: self.images[indexPath.item].asset, thumbnail: false)
            selectedImage = image

            self.selectedImages.append(SelectedImage(image: selectedImage!, index: indexPath.item))

            self.images[indexPath.item].image = selectedImage
            self.images[indexPath.item].page = self.selectedImages.count

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageView.image = selectedImage
                cell.hideIndicator()
                cell.setSelected(page: self.selectedImages.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the UI freeze or not?

Comment: Nope, everything in the UI works as normal except for the indicator not showing. The scroll is enabled and it reacts to other selections as well!

Comment: Is it possible that, by the time the line `cell.hideIndicator()` runs, the cell has been re-used for a different item? In which case, it will hide an indicator that it should not hide.

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried to disable `cell.hideIndicator()` just to see what would happen. When not hiding any indicators and just leave them there, the indicators for ALL images in the collection view become active after approx. 12 images selected. This also happens when selecting the images in a consecutive order.